# Save Iframe content using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I need to save the content of Iframe which contains an image and other information as Image using javascript.

Any method like frame.print() which automaticaly open the print window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your parent document and iframe's document are on the same domain, you can do as :

```
var idoc = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
window.open(idoc.getElementById("idOfImageInTheIframe").src, "download_win");
```

Otherwise(not on the same domain), a security exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your help but my document are not on the same domain. Please provide me any solution for the above problem.

Comment: I am sorry. I think it is not possible to do it on the client side using iframe nor XMLHttpRequest. You can do at serverside if possible.

Comment: Hey! So I have been looking for a way to load an Iframe from a src (stored on the PC), and then edit the contents of the Iframe, and then save the new contents of the Iframe to the same src file. Is this possible?